# Concatenation in exec() method Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Suppose the code goes like :

```
if (int i = 1) {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl D:\\Soft\\Eclipse\\WorkSpace\\FirstPerl.pl");
        process.waitFor();
}
else if(int i = 2) {
     process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl D:\\Soft\\Eclipse\\WorkSpace\\secondPerl.pl");
     process.waitFor();
}

//so on ..
```

Instead of repeating the path `D:\\Soft\\Eclipse\\WorkSpace\\` several times, is there any way through which I can declare the path as `String` and achieve something as below:

```
String path = "D:\\Soft\\Eclipse\\WorkSpace\\";
if (int i = 1) {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl"+path+"FirstPerl.pl");
    process.waitFor();
}
else if(int i = 2){
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl"+path+"secondPerl.pl");
    process.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile, `int i = 1` returns `1` which is not a boolean that is required in the if statement.

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Why don't you just do it, fix the compilation errors, test it, and fix the bugs you'll find by doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is really basic...

```
String[] scripts = new String[] { "firstPerl.pl", "secondPerl.pl" };
Path script = Paths.get(path, scripts[i-1]); // or 0-base i in the first place
process = Runtime.exec("perl " + script.toAbsolutePath());
process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

String path ="D:\Soft\Eclipse\WorkSpace\";

int i = 0;

if(i ==1){

String newpath = "perl"+path+"FirstPerl.pl";

process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(newpath);process.waitFor();

}else if(i == 2){

String newpath = "perl"+path+"secondPerl.pl";

process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(newpath);

process.waitFor();

}